# EF Core Fails to transfer data into new SQL Server DB from old one

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

**Steps to reproduce**

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.2 web application with the backend SQL Server DB made in Entity Framework Core from this tutorial. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-2.2

To summarise the steps.

1. Download the project in the link.
2. Go to `appsettings.json`.
3. Change database name in connection string to `ContosoUniversity2`.
4. Save your changes and build the project.
5. Ensure no instance of the program is running and use CLI (Command Line Interface) or PMC (Package Management Console) and navigate to the project folder and enter this command. `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`.
6. Now enter command`dotnet ef database update`.

**Expected behaviour**

Entity Framework migrates data from previous database named ContosoUniversity1 to ContosoUniversity2 including all the columns and tables. It has worked for the author in Visual Studio 2019.

**Actual behaviour**

I am only seeing the creation of all tables and columns. There is no data other than in __EFMigrationsHistory which has a single row for the migration history. I get this output from CLI.

```
`Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'SchoolContext' us
ing provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (666ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTime
out='60']
      CREATE DATABASE [ContosoUniversity2];
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (161ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTime
out='60']
      IF SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') <> 5
      BEGIN
          ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity2] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
      END;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeo
ut='30']
      CREATE TABLE [__EFMigrationsHistory] (
          [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
          [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeou
t='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeou
t='30']
      SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
      FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
      ORDER BY [MigrationId];
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20191227004521_InitialCreate'.
Applying migration '20191227004521_InitialCreate'.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeou
t='30']
      CREATE TABLE [Course] (
          [CourseID] int NOT NULL,
          [Title] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [Credits] int NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_Course] PRIMARY KEY ([CourseID])
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeou
t='30']
      CREATE TABLE [Student] (
          [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
          [LastName] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [FirstMidName] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [EnrollmentDate] datetime2 NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeou
t='30']
      CREATE TABLE [Enrollment] (
          [EnrollmentID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
          [CourseID] int NOT NULL,
          [StudentID] int NOT NULL,
          [Grade] int NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_Enrollment] PRIMARY KEY ([EnrollmentID]),
          CONSTRAINT [FK_Enrollment_Course_CourseID] FOREIGN KEY ([CourseID]) RE
FERENCES [Course] ([CourseID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT [FK_Enrollment_Student_StudentID] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentID])
 REFERENCES [Student] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeou
t='30']
      CREATE INDEX [IX_Enrollment_CourseID] ON [Enrollment] ([CourseID]);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeou
t='30']
      CREATE INDEX [IX_Enrollment_StudentID] ON [Enrollment] ([StudentID]);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeou
t='30']
      INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
      VALUES (N'20191227004521_InitialCreate', N'2.2.6-servicing-10079');
Done.`
```

**Environment data:**

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.1.7601
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win7-x64
```

Comment: Are you expecting the **data** in all the tables to have been also copied across?

Comment: Yes @BrendanGreen because it shows in the image in the MS tutorial that the data has been copied across. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations/_static/students-index.png?view=aspnetcore-2.2.

Comment: I think you missread a `migration` word here. Migration is used to migrate data in the **same** db from one version (of tables structure) to another.

Comment: @vasily-sib So it is supposed to copy the data across, just like I thought. But i have read and re-read the steps. I wonder what I could have missed.

Comment: @JordanNash "migrations" do not copy data. They simply make changes to the database schema. In this case, you have effectively set a new connection string. I assume the "new" database doesnt exist yet, so the migration applies commands that will create the new database, and create the schema (tables, indexes, views etc) so that it matches what is configured in the EF context in your application. If the database existed already with data, the commands would preserve this data if possible.

Comment: @gerryc.inc Right I think understand, thanks. It just confused me a bit when the tutorial shows an image of data in the new database when you are really applying the migrations to create a new database with the same schema without copying data across from the previous database.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the migrations. The solution was to revert to a previous backup in my backup folder and copy and paste the code from the tutorial instead of hand writing it. Turns out I only had one line misspelled and was able correct that.